# typeerror cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: angular

It gives typeerror cannot read property 'push' of undefined, when data pushing into Array. I want to add data into array for every loop.

```
if (s > 0) {
    for (let key in result.shiftStatusList) {
        var data = result.shiftStatusList[key];
        this.shiftStatusList = data.status;
        this.shiftName = data.shiftName;
        for (let mod in data.centreStatusList) {
            var moderator = data.centreStatusList[mod]
            this.centreStatusList = moderator.status
            this.moderatorView = true;

            for (let sup in moderator.hallStatusList) {
                var Supervisor = moderator.hallStatusList[sup]
                this.hallStatusList = Supervisor.status;
                this.SupervisorView = true;
                if (this.hallStatusList == "INCOMPLETE") {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.Shift.push({ shiftStatusList: this.shiftStatusList, shiftName: this.shiftName, centreStatusList: this.centreStatusList, hallStatusList: this.hallStatusList });
}
```

Comment: where is the shift variable, please name your variables in camel case and i think you should define the variable as shift=[] , in your declaration part

Comment: you need declare your variable like Shift:any[]=[] //see the =[]

Answer (score 0):

Assign your shift variable to an empty array like below.

```
Shift: any[] = [];
```